# Best way of globally handling requests timeout errors with Axios and show alert to user?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

This is my current setup of handling request errors:

This "loginButtonHandler()" gets executed when pressed the login function, inside I'm executing the "authAPi.login()" function and waiting to see the result. If the result is successful I will navigate to the application, if it's not I will change my state to show the error message.

```
async function loginButtonHandler() {
    const result = await authAPI.login(formInput)
    if (result.success) {
        props.navigation.navigate('App')
    } else {
        setLoginError(result.error)
    }
}
```

In my "authAPI.login()" I try to do the login POST request, store the token in local storage, set the token in Axios default headers and finally return success=True.

```
export async function login(data){
    try {
        // Send login request to server and get token
        const response = await axios.post('auth/login/', data)
        const token = response.data.key

        // Save token on local storage
        await AsyncStorage.setItem('token', token)

        // Set token in default request headers
        axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Token ${token}`

        // If success return true
        return {success: true}
    }
    catch (error) {
        // If timeout is triggered (error.code='ECONNABORTED') show alert to user.
        if (error.code === 'ECONNABORTED'){
            Alert.alert("Error",  'Connection to server timeout.')
            return {success: false }
        }

        // If server responds with wrong credentials
        if (error.response.data['non_field_errors'][0] === 'Unable to log in with provided credentials.'){
            return {success: false, error: 'Wrong username or password.'}
        }

        // For unforeseen errors throw the error
        throw error
    }
}
```

Currently, if I want to add more functions that have requests to the server, I need to add this error handling to all request function catch blocks:

```
catch (error) {
    if (error.code === 'ECONNABORTED'){
        Alert.alert("Error",  'Connection to server timeout.')
        return {success: false }
    }
    ...
```

I'm trying to figure out a way of adding this error handling globally so the user will get an alert for any request timeout without having to add it to each request.

I was able to add this interceptor:

```
instance.interceptors.response.use((response)=> response, (error)=> {
    if (error.code === 'ECONNABORTED') {
        Alert.alert("Error",  'Connection to server timeout.')
    }

    return Promise.reject(error);
  })
```

But that doesn't seem to help since it seems like I still need to add this to all request error catch blocks:

```
    if (error.code === 'ECONNABORTED'){
        return {success: false }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

That is how I do it

```
    if (response.ok) {
    // do data conversion here if needed
    AsyncStorage.setItem('token', response.data.access_token);
    AsyncStorage.setItem('refresh_token', response.data.refresh_token);
    AsyncStorage.setItem('clientId', response.data.clientId);

    yield put(SigninActions.signinSuccess(response.data));
  } else if (
    response.problem === 'NETWORK_ERROR' ||
    response.problem === 'TIMEOUT_ERROR'
  ) {
    yield put(
      SigninActions.signinFailure(
        'There is a network problem. Please try again.',
      ),
    );
  }
```

You can use this awesome library to show Alerts:
[react-native-alert-dialogues](https://github.com/Ali-Haider-Ch/react-native-alert-dialogues)